# Sudo install on remote machine

Tags: linux, root

I need to install some packages using yum (I am trying to follow the steps from here: https://root.cern/install/dependencies/), but when I try, I am told that I need to be root to perform this command. However, I am just a user on the remote linux compute cluster I am trying to install this on. Is there a way to do this without root privileges? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.

This question is too general but I will try to answer:

It is possible to unpack the contents of packages into the home directory, but it is very likely that they will want to write to folders where the average user does not have write permission. Also, configuration files are usually loaded from folders where it is not possible to write files.

Rather, I recommend compiling the required program from source code. Then it is possible to specify that the program will work only within the user's directory.

A similar situation can occur for other programming languages, but there are already specific solutions and there is no room to discuss them in more detail.